# What WOPI API needs to be implemented in order to support createDocument OfficeJs API calls

Tags: ms-word, office-js, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I am developing a Word Online add-in that is supposed to operate in an environment with a custom WOPI host.
We faced issues with a certain Office JS API which appears not to be supported. But we are struggling with identifying what exactly is missing.

Could anyone please help me to figure out what WOPI API needs to be implemented in order to support createDocument OfficeJs API calls?

For [createDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.application?view=word-js-preview#createdocument-base64file-) we supposed to receive [PutRelativeFile](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/PutRelativeFile.html), however, there was a client-side call to https://word-edit.officeapps.live.com/we/CreateNewDocument.aspx which resulted in a redirect to the Outage.html. Nothing seemed to come to the WOPI host.
We already verified that [SupportsUpdate](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-supportsupdate) is set to true and [UserCanNotWriteRelative](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-usercannotwriterelative) is set to false.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(base64String);
    context.load(myNewDoc);

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            myNewDoc.open();
            context.sync();
        })
```

[image: RichApi.GeneralException screenshot]

Is there any configuration to allow this apart from mentioned above?

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check whether there are any incoming requests on the WOPI Host side? Any requests that would end up as 4** or 5**... and is there any more detailed info than "Sorry, something went wrong"? What leads you to think that it's caused by the WOPI host?